# having a list of urls starting with https and return output list having url starts with https and http both

Tags: python, list

I am having data as

```
data = ​set(['https://a.com/', 'https://b.com'])
```

I want output to be like

```
​set(['https://a.com/', 'https://b.com', 'http://a.com/', 'http://b.com'])
```

i just want to append same url with `http` as well as `https`.
**Note :** I want to do this with minimum line(need to be 1 line).
I tried

```
>>>out = set([i.replace('https', 'http') for i in m] + [i for i in m])
>>>set(['https://abccakes.dbmonline.net/grappelli/bookmark/get/?path=/admin/', 'https://abccakes.dbmonline.net/admin/', 'http://abccakes.dbmonline.net/grappelli/bookmark/get/?path=/admin/', 'http://abccakes.dbmonline.net/admin/'])
```

It is working fine but i do not want to use replace .i want to replace https with http as element of list.

Comment: What is wrong with using `str.replace()` to replace `https` with `http`? You are going to have to use string manipulation **at some point** here.

Comment: if my url is  like https://abchttps.com  then i will face problem that's why i do not want to use it

Comment: Then specify that as your problem; you want to handle URLs with `https` elsewhere in them. You can limit the number of replacements with the `str.replace()` function, for example.

Comment: @PrashantGaur You can pass an optional count to `str.replace.`

Comment: If you really want to do it properly, use the `urlparse` module to parse out URLs into their constituent parts.

Comment: I tried `data, links = set(['https://a.com/', 'https://b.com']),  set(['https://a.com/', 'https://b.com']); for d in data: links.add(d.replace('https', 'http'))`

Comment: @PrashantGaur how about replace('https:', 'http:') ?

Comment: @zhangxaochen  it sound good .. that may solve problem ... but i think i need to follow martijn advice to use urlparse module

Comment: Limiting the number of replacements won't do for input like `http://some.thing.com?key=value;key2=https://value;key3=value`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that is ok what you are saying we can achieve that but i want to solve problem with n complexity ... that solution will take 2n complexity

Comment: @djangoman If you're looking for a faster solution, then use `set.union`. Check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a faster solution here, then it's better to use `set.union` or `set.update` if you want to update the original set itself.

```
In [16]: data = set('https://{}.com'.format(''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(10))) f
or _ in xrange(10**5))                                                                           

In [17]: %timeit set([i.replace('https', 'http', 1) for i in data] + [i for i in data])          
10 loops, best of 3: 252 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit data.union(x.replace('https', 'http', 1) for x in data)                         
1 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit from itertools import chain; set(chain.from_iterable([x, x.replace('https', 'htt
p', 1)] for x in data))                                                                          
10 loops, best of 3: 190 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = set([re.sub(r'^https:', 'http:', i) for i in m] + [i for i in m])
```